# left join returning null value instead of records value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to fetch all records of left table and matched of right table . But left join is returning null for not matched records from left table instead of their values.

```
            $questions=DB::table('questions')
                    ->leftJoin('sections',function($join ){
                        $join->on('questions.questionid','=','sections.questionid');
                    })
                    ->where('questions.formid',$formId)
                    ->get();
```

Is it the nature of left join or some thing is wrong?
How can I reach to my goal?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'questions.id` instead of `'questions.questionid` in your query callback?! And also - why don't you use [eloquent relation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) methods? You loose a lot of functionality of eloquent when using raw queries and elqouent is amazing to work with - and not even too complicated to get started!

Comment: could you add your schema of these two tables?

Comment: No. it's questions.questionid

Answer (score 2):

A [left join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause) will return ALL records from the left table, whether they have matching records or not. Null means there is no matching record in the right table.

Comment: Is there any way to get left table's value instead of null?

Comment: yes, if  you don't care about a match you can just use  `join` instate of `left join`